# How to import data with a mapping to custom address field?

Tags: administration, data

I have made a custom object which has various fields, out of which one is a custom address field. Now, as per documentation Data Import Wizard does not support the custom address field. So what are the other options to import data using an excel file with that mapping? or if there are any other workarounds.

Comment: Have you tried using Data loader [Data Loader Guide](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_data_loader.pdf) ?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative options you can consider to import data with mapping is **Data Loader**.
**Data Loader** : A desktop application provided by Salesforce, to import data into Salesforce. **Data Loader supports custom address fields** and provides more flexibility in mapping fields. With Data Loader, you can map the address fields from your Excel file to the corresponding custom address field in Salesforce.

References : [Apex Data Loader In Salesforce](https://salesforcedrillers.com/learn-salesforce/apex-data-loader-in-salesforce/)

[Data Loader Guide](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to deal with the complexities of Data Loader, you can upload directly from Excel or Google Sheets using [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/), [XL-Connector 365](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104382023?src=office&tab=Overview), or [G-Connector](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/gconnector_for_salesforce/971770431958)